# Get json object values and store as arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, database, datatables

[image: sample array of object image]

I am trying to get the values of each object array as seen on the image, and store these values as an array without including their keys using javascript and store these array on a datatable.
The array should look like this

```
[
    ['david','female','john','e6a33eee180b07e563d74fee8c2c66b8',1,1,'roger63'],
    ['rogers','Male','paul','2e7dc6b8a1598f4f75c3eaa47958ee2f',1,2,'mike28']
]
```

I tried using

```
$.map(a, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
```

but the result i got is the same as the image like nothing happened.

can anyone help me? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `array.map(obj => Object.values(obj));`? Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i did. it still displayed the same result, which still includes the key.

Comment: _What_ still displayed the same result? Could you [edit] your question and include your attempt?

Comment: @ChrizJee Did you assign the result of `map` to a variable and display that? It doesn't modify the array in place.

Comment: @Xufox yes, I am expecting an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples:

```
const objArr = [{
    "first_name": "david",
    "gender": "Female",
    "last_name": "john",
    "password": "asdasd",
    "status": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "username": "rogers63"
}, {
    "first_name": "rogers",
    "gender": "Male",
    "last_name": "paul",
    "password": "qweqwe",
    "status": 1,
    "user_id": 2,
    "username": "mike28"
}];
const arrArr = objArr.map(x => Object.values(x));
console.log(arrArr);
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/msdm4r6r/).

Comment: It's just what i'm looking for, thank you @annoyingmouse

Comment: To be fair, @Xufox had the same answer in a comment to your post. But thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Lol. Try this:

`array.reduce(function(total, current) {
  total = total.concat(Object.values(current));
    return total;
}, []);`

Comment: Why `reduce`? You just need `map`.

Comment: Hard to tell from the question, but I think he/she is trying to reduce to flatten & reduce to 1 single array.